# Problems in Linux Mint 13 MATE with NTFS partitions

Tags: linux, ntfs, linux-mint, file-permissions, mate

I'm using Linux Mint 13 MATE (32 bit).
With Caja file manager (based on Nautilus 2.x) I can create, modify and remove folders and files on NTFS partitions whitout problems.
But, for example, when I have a compressed file (.zip, .7z, ...) in a NTFS partition I can't extract it (with File-Roller, Peazip, ...). But I can extract the same file in a ext4 partition perfectly.

What might the problem be? Are there (maybe) file permissions for each application?